# Custom PHP Session Class

Tags: php, database, oop, class, session

What I want to do is write a custom PHP session class that stores sessions in the database without using `session_set_save_handler()`.

The purpose of this is so I can easily store data using `serialize()` and return it using `unserialize()`.

I've been looking all day, can't find anything on this subject. Can anyone help get me started or link me to a useful tutorial?

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is that you don't have a clear idea for what you are looking for.

Comment: Why would session_set_save_handler() prevent you from using serialize()? The purpose of session_set_save_handler() is to customize  the sessions. The only way to not use it is to create your own session handling entirely from scratch (meaning you couldn't use the `$_SESSION` global either ... at least not in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Cfreak that's what I'm looking for. An entire custom handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the build-in PHP session for that, you can set the cookie yourself, read it and validate it again, from that point on you got a fully functioning session!

```
function createCookieString($id, $user, $created)
{
    $cookieData = array();
    $hash = $this->hashSession($id, $user, $created);

    $cookieData[] = $id;
    $cookieData[] = $user;
    $cookieData[] = $created;
    $cookieData[] = $hash;

    return implode(':', $cookieData);
}

function hashSession($id, $user, $created)
{
    $cookieSalt = 'Your Cookie Salt'; //google what a salt is in hashing if neccecary
    return md5($id.$user.$created.$cookieSalt);
}

function parseCookieString($string)
{
    return explode(':', $string);

}
```

To set the cookie, just use the setcookie function of php.

You just have to store the session in your database. Its usually verry simple, just a table with ID, userID, created (beeing the timestamp), you dont need the hash to be in your db because its a reusable secret.

feel free to ask any more questions!

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go, if I like it, I'll rate you top answer. :)